# How to exclude major upgrade for specific dependencies when using "group-all" merge requests in Renovate?

Tags: gitlab, renovate

I would like to prevent [Renovate](https://docs.renovatebot.com/) from making major upgrades for some dependencies **but still allow minor and patch upgrade for those dependencies**. Using `ignoreDeps` excludes them completely which is not optimal. I also need to have all suggested upgrades of each run in one Gitlab merge request, so using separate `matchUpdateTypes` groups does not suit my use-case.

Is there a way to achieve what I am looking for?

Concrete example in a project using Angular 14, that Renovate should not try to upgrade to 15 but still give me the latest 14.x upgrades:

```json
"@angular/router": "14.2.7",   // what I have now
"@angular/router": "14.2.10",  // what should be suggested
"@angular/router": "15.0.0",   // what should be avoided
```

My general package rules across all repos looks like following:

```json
"packageRules": [
  {
    "groupName": "all dependencies",
    "groupSlug": "all",
    "matchPackagePatterns": [
      "*"
    ],
    "matchUpdateTypes": [
      "major",
      "minor",
      "patch"
    ]
  }
],
```

And I specify the specific dependencies to ignore in the `renovate.json` file of each repo like such:

```json
{
  "$schema": "https://docs.renovatebot.com/renovate-schema.json"
  "ignoreDeps": [
    "@angular/router"
  ]
}
```

But this prevents *all* updates. I've tried playing around with the schema, this did just ignore the config altogether:

```json
// BROKEN
{
  "$schema": "https://docs.renovatebot.com/renovate-schema.json"
  "major": {
    "ignoreDeps": [
      "@angular/router"
    ]
  }
}
```

And overriding the `packageRules` at repo level was also unsuccessful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
"packageRules": [
...
  {
    "matchPackageNames": ["@angular/router"],
    "allowedVersions": "<15.0.0"
  },
...
]
```

Comment: Do you know if this would also be possible to configure at the repo level (in the `renovate.json` file)? I may want to forbid major updates of some lib for one repo but allow it for another one.
EDIT: I realize now, I could rewrite my `renovate.json` to use `packageRules` instead of `ignoreDeps` and have that kind of granular control at the repo level. Correct? I'll try this and report back.

Comment: Works as advertised! I was also able to use `matchPackagePatterns` to ignore all `@angular/*` packages.